# Flink 1.6 Async IO - How to increase throughput when enriching a stream, using a REST service call?

Tags: apache-flink

I am currently on Flink version 1.6 and am facing an issue with AsyncIO wherein the performance is not up to my expectation.

I am sure I am doing something wrong in my implementation, so any advice/suggestions would be appreciated.

Issue Synopsis - 
I am consuming a stream of ids. 
For each id, I need to call a REST service.
I've implemented a RichAsyncFunction, which performs the async REST call.

Here's the relevant code method and the asyncInvoke method

```
// these are initialized in the open method
ExecutorService executorService = 
ExecutorService.newFixedThreadPool(n);
CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = ...
Gson gson = ...

public void asyncInvoke(String key, final ResultFuture<Item> resultFuture) throws Exception {

    executorService.submit(new Runnable() {

        client.execute(new HttpGet(new URI("http://myservice/" + key)), new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {
             @Override
                public void completed(final HttpResponse response) {
                    System.out.println("completed successfully");
                    Item item = gson.fromJson(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity), Item.class);
                    resultFuture.complete(Collections.singleton(item));
                }
        });
    });
```

}

With the above implementation, I've tried :-

- Increasing the parallelism of the enrichment operation
- Increasing the number of threads in the executor service
- Using apache http async client, I've tried tweaking the connection manager settings - setDefaultMaxPerRoute and setMaxTotal.

I am consistently getting a throughput of about 100 requests/sec. The service is able to handle more than 5k per sec.
What am I doing wrong, and how can I improve this ?

Comment: Have you checked for backpressure in the Flink job (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/monitoring/back_pressure.html)? That will help indicate where the bottleneck is. Also, are you using orderedWait, or unorderedWait, and with what capacity?

Comment: I assume whatever you're using for `n` (creating the threaded pool) is what you're also using for `setDefaultMaxPerRoute` and `setMaxTotal` and the capacity parameter for `AsyncDataStream.unorderedWait()`. If you call  `AsyncDataStream.unorderedWait()` without a capacity parameter, it defaults to 100, which is an interesting number given your current results :)

Comment: @DavidAnderson I am using unorderedWait, and I haven't set a capacity parameter. I'll definitely check out the backpressure link you have shared.

Comment: @kkrugler It's an interesting observation. I hadn't supplied a capacity parameter. I'll share the results, after tweaking it. Thanks for the pointer!